# urlrewrite using an url parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cookies, url-rewriting

I have a problem with apache and .htaccess. What is my need: make an url rewrite from www.mywebsite.com to rome.mywebsite.com or lasangeles.mywebsite.com

How the script works:
start the php script
read a cookie and get a value (i.e. rome)
the script will send an header location to index.php?zone=rome
using the parameter the .htacess clould make an url rewrite like rome.mywebsite.com

What I did:
- I have created a wildcard DNS record A like *.mywebsite.com
- I am using the follow rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mywebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-_]+).mywebsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}?zone=%2 [NC,QSA]
```

but it doesn't work!

Before post here, I searched in the site but all answers  were not good for my problem.

Do you have ideas to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance to all

Comment: if you're using PHP to do some processing and then redirecting, is there a reason for not redirecting from PHP to rome.example.com or losangeles.example.com directly? Why do you need the whole htaccess redirect?

Comment: I need an urlrewrite based on the parameter in the url

Comment: You mention you start the PHP script, read a cookie, get a value, and send a header location to `index.php?zone=XXX`. Why don't you send that header to `XXX.example.com` instead ?

Comment: because I can't create infnity numbuer of subdomain as the cities in the worlds, I need just the rewrite the url

Comment: ...if you do the rewrite you use that same subdomain?!? All requests will get served by the same method

Comment: Can you halp to to solve my problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([w]{3})?\.?([a-z0-9-]+)\.mywebsite\.com
RewriteRule ^/? /index.php?zone=%2 [QSA]
```

Try this one, just do the rest to fix it if there's an error.
I've just given you an example, but still, it's not tested.

If the code above did not work, then try the code below:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.mywebsite\.com
RewriteRule ^/? /index.php?zone=%1 [QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mywebsite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([a-z0-9-]+)\.mywebsite\.com
RewriteRule ^/? /index.php?zone=%1 [QSA]
```